# Record count after distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

I am using following query for the pagination

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT a.*, rownum row_num FROM (
    select distinct field1, field2, ...
      COUNT(*) OVER () RESULT_COUNT
    from table1
    where condition1
    order by someField desc
  )a 
  WHERE rownum < :maxRow 
)WHERE row_num > = :minRow;
```

I am getting result_count=294 (which is total record matching condition) whereas total record returned after distinct is 61. How can I have 61 in result_count. In other words I need the total record count after using distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this you mean

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT a.*, rownum row_num FROM (
    select field1, field2, ...
      COUNT(DISTINCT field1) OVER () RESULT_COUNT
    from table1
    where condition1
    order by someField desc
  )a 
  WHERE rownum < :maxRow 
)WHERE row_num > = :minRow;
```

Comment: Don't we need distinct keyword in field1 in third select?